# Better way call a non-linear regression model in curve() drawings in R?

Tags: r, plot, non-linear-regression

I have been learning how to plot graphs and curves in R, and have used the `plot()` and `curve()` functions with a set of data to plot both the data and the curve. However, I don't believe I am using the most efficient methods.

What I have done is set up 2 vectors from a `data.frame` that and then I assigned an object (call it `o`) to the `nls()` function like `o<-nls(y~I(a*x^3)+I(b*x^2)+I(c*x)+d)`. I could get all of the coefficient values for `o` (`a`,`b`,`c`,`d`) by calling `o`. I can then plug approximations for those values into the `curve()` function after plotting the points. That works, but I was wondering if there is any way to plug `o` directly into the `curve` function so I don't have to retype each coefficient?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input so that we can test possible solutions. Chances are good this can be solved with the `predict()` function.

Comment: So, if I am following, you would prefer to see something like my response to Roland below. I probably could have organized these out step-wise a little better here, so I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your function is a polynomial and therefore linear in its coefficients. Anyway, it works the same with `nls` as with `lm`. Specify the data.frame for the fit:

```
o <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE), data = DF)
plot(y ~ x, data = DF)
curve(predict(o, newdata = data.frame(x = x)), add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Roland, doesn't `curve` need an expression (in this case a polynomial in x with the coefficients from `o`)? Whereas you could use `lines()` to add a curve using the `predict` function to get the `y` values explicitly.

Comment: @eipi10 Yes, curve needs a function or an expression containing x. In this example I pass it the latter. Create some dummy data and test it. It works (there might be a typo in my code since it's untested). I use this construction regularly.

Comment: Thanks for this Roland. So I tried to reproduce my results using this methodology and I received a different curve:
Originally: I have DF<-read.csv(.....)
 x<-DF[,1]
 y<-DF[,2]
o<-nls(y~I(c1*x^3)+I(c2*x^2)+I(c3*x)+c4)
which had coeff: -3.712e-05  7.559e-03 -7.784e-01  2.719e+01 
Now, I used:
o<-lm(y~poly(x,3,raw=TRUE))
curve(predict(o),add=TRUE)) 
I **did get the same coefficients** but the lines plotted on the graph aren't the same. Quite puzzled. I assume you can leave out the optional data in lm() if you have the data already fited with the lm() function?

Comment: You **must** follow my example to the details. Pass a data.frame to the model function and newdata to predict as shown. Otherwise this does not work correctly.

Comment: Scratch that Roland, I figured it out. I forgot that my data went through a slight modification, and when I re-plotted, the new curve using the lm() fit perfectly. Thank you for the help! Really quickly, I noticed in the documentation that the newdata parameter is optional, but it seems in this case it is necessary to specify x as input. Is that to specify the range over which the prediction is to occur? I received an error when omitting that value.

Comment: In a comment above I wrote that curve needs an expression containing x.